# Show alert after few second in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rxjs

I am trying to create an APP which will show alert once I click on any item and this alert will fade away after few second.

I have created a very small app to test this, where I am adding an element to the state and displaying it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>React 17 </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.13.15/babel.min.js"></script>

  <!-- babel is required in order to parse JSX -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/babel">


    class Test extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          showAlert: []
        }
      }

      showAlert = (e) => {
        //alert(e.target.value);

        const old = this.state.showAlert;



        this.setState((prevState) => {
          let arr = prevState.showAlert;
          arr.push(e.target.value);
          return { showAlert: arr }
        });

        setTimeout(
          function () {
            this.setState((prevState) => {
              const array = prevState.showAlert.filter(element => element !== e.target.value);
              return { showAlert: array }
            });
          }
            .bind(this),
          2000
        );

      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>

            {
              this.state.showAlert.length > 0 &&

              <ul>
                {this.state.showAlert.map((value, index) => {
                  return <li key={index}>{value}</li>
                })}
              </ul>
            }

            <select onChange={this.showAlert} multiple>
              <option value="Test 1">Test 1</option>
              <option value="Test 2">Test 2</option>
              <option value="Test 3">Test 3</option>
              <option value="Test 4">Test 4</option>
              <option value="Test 5">Test 5</option>
              <option value="Test 6">Test 6</option>
            </select>

          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById("app"));
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem I am facing is, an alert notification is disappearing only if I click once if I click another item before two seconds, only the last item is disappearing not the first one. https://www.loom.com/share/0287300eaef147aeaa5d11e9dd108d7e

Comment: You're using `index` as a key, but changing the order of the alert array, so React has no way of storing consistent state for each alert. Rather you should use a unique identifier as key for each alert.

Comment: @pilchard - I am sorry but can you make a change in code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using functional components. The array of alerts is held in state in the parent, while individual `Alert` components hold their own timer set in a `useEffect` and cleaned up appropriately. Each alert is given a unique `id` to be used as key.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [alerts, setAlerts] = React.useState([]);

  const showAlert = (e) => {
    const newAlert = {
      id: `${e.target.value}_${performance.now()}`,
      value: e.target.value
    };
    setAlerts(prev => [...prev, newAlert]);
  };

  const clearAlert = (_id) => {
    setAlerts(prev => prev.filter(({ id }) => id !== _id));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select onChange={showAlert}>
        <option value="Test 1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="Test 2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="Test 3">Test 3</option>
        <option value="Test 4">Test 4</option>
        <option value="Test 5">Test 5</option>
        <option value="Test 6">Test 6</option>
      </select>
      {!!alerts.length &&
        <ul>
          {alerts.map(alert =>
            <li key={alert.id}>
              <Alert alert={alert} clearAlert={clearAlert} />
            </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      }
    </div>
  )
}

const Alert = ({ alert, clearAlert }) => {

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const visible = setTimeout(() => clearAlert(alert.id), 3000);
    return () => clearTimeout(visible);
  }, []);

  return (
    <p>{alert.value}</p>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you @pilchard, but I am still learning and seems like the whole code is changed. Is there something I can do inside my code to achieve the desired result.